# VB.net serialport.readline vs datareceived vs threading

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, serial-port, readline

Novice (very novice) programmer, working in VB.net... I have read many different views about this, seams threading would be the best solution, but it's a little over my head at this point.
What I am trying to accomplish is reading a line of data from serial port (Bluetooth). The length of the data is always the same, and always ends with CRLF (data is ASCII). I am reading data from a digital torque wrench, the user has to tighten 6 bolts with the wrench, each bolt sends a string of data through the serial port. I read this raw data, and extract from the string the actual torque value and save it to database. I have the database connection working I can read the data and extract the value I need. The issue is if the use has to quit reading for some reason, I cannot exit out of the event. I have tried adding a button that sets a variable to true (Dim BoolEscape as Boolean to "True"). Then added an Application.DoEvents() call followed by a check to see if BoolEscape = True then exit sub... From what I have read this doesn't work and never will.

The data string received is formated: "RE,001,100.0,16/08/20,12:45:10CRLF"

Below is some code from my BtnStartRead_Click event... I am only showing 2 bolts  worth as it just repeats.... I believe threading is the answer but again, don't understand how it works....

```
 Private Sub btnStartRead_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStartRead.Click
    On Error GoTo err_handle
    boolEscape = False
    txtBolt1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 128)
    txtBolt2.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 128)
    txtBolt3.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 128)
    txtBolt4.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 128)
    txtBolt5.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 128)
    txtBolt6.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 128)
    lblA1.Visible = True
    ShowRXon()
    txtRaw1.Text = mySerialPort.ReadLine
    ShowRXoff()
    txtBolt1.Text = txtRaw1.Text.Substring(7, 4)
    If checkValue(txtBolt1.Text) = False Then
        txtBolt1.BackColor = Color.Red
    End If
    lblA1.Visible = False
    lblA2.Visible = True

    Application.DoEvents()
    If boolEscape = True Then
        MsgBox("You have STOPPED the measurment logging...", vbOKOnly)
        boolEscape = False
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ShowRXon()
    txtRaw2.Text = mySerialPort.ReadLine
    ShowRXoff()
    txtBolt2.Text = txtRaw2.Text.Substring(7, 4)
    If checkValue(txtBolt2.Text) = False Then
        txtBolt2.BackColor = Color.Red
    End If
    lblA2.Visible = False
    lblA3.Visible = True

    Application.DoEvents()
    If boolEscape = True Then
        MsgBox("You have STOPPED the measurment logging...", vbOKOnly)
        boolEscape = False
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

How would I go about adding this to a separate thread, or id the datareceived event a better approach du the the line being always the same length and always ending with CRLF... and if so, how cold I modify it to use this instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, you should be handling the `DataReceived` event of the `SerialPort`. You can initiate whatever process you like in the `Click` event of your `Button` but it's only the initiation. The `DataReceived` event will be raised when your `SerialPort` object receives data and you then process that data. If you expect to receive one line of data six times then you can call `ReadLine` in the event handler and the event will likely be raised six times.

There's no need to initiate any multi-threading because it's already done for you, i.e. the `DataReceived` event is raised on a secondary thread, therefore your event handler is executed on a secondary thread. That means that you cannot access any controls directly in that event handler or any method called from that event handler. You will need to marshal a call to the UI thread in order to update the UI. Here's a simple example of sending multiple commands to a `SerialPort` and displaying the responses:

```vb
Private commands As Queue(Of String)

Private Sub SendNextCommand()
    If commands.Any() Then
        SerialPort1.WriteLine(commands.Dequeue())
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    commands = New Queue(Of String)({"First", "Second", "Third"})

    SendNextCommand()
End Sub

Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(sender As Object, e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
    Dim response = SerialPort1.ReadLine()

    'This event is raised on a secondary thread so we must marshal to the UI thread to update the UI.
    TextBox1.BeginInvoke(Sub() TextBox1.AppendText(response & Environment.NewLine))

    SendNextCommand()
End Sub
```